# Create New Table with Unpivot and Dynamic Columns

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, unpivot

I have been trying to unpivot a large database with dynamic columns while keeping two indexed columns. I can't get it to save as a new table in SQL Server Management Studio as a new table. Right now I'm getting 'An INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable.'

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

create table pivot_columns ([Prime Item Nbr] NVARCHAR(MAX), [Store Nbr] NVARCHAR(MAX))


insert into pivot_columns

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(column_name)
                      FROM information_schema.columns
                      WHERE table_name = 'POSSalesMicro'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Prime Item Nbr' 
                        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Store Nbr'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');




SELECT @query = 'WITH Unpivoted 
                AS
                (
                    SELECT [Prime Item Nbr], [Store Nbr], columns, value
                    FROM POSSalesMicro
                    UNPIVOT
                    (
                       columns
                       FOR value IN('+ @cols + ')
                    ) AS u
                ) 
                SELECT 
                  [Prime Item Nbr], 
                  [Store Nbr],
                  columns,
                  CAST(CASE WHEN value LIKE ''% POS Sales'' THEN REPLACE(value,''POS Sales'', '''')
                       WHEN value LIKE ''LR%'' THEN REPLACE(value,''LR '', '''')
                  END AS INT) AS WMWeek
                FROM Unpivoted';


EXECUTE(@query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make the insert part of your dynamic sql. Something along these lines.

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(column_name)
                      FROM information_schema.columns
                      WHERE table_name = 'POSSalesMicro'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Prime Item Nbr' 
                        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Store Nbr'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'WITH Unpivoted 
                AS
                (
                    SELECT [Prime Item Nbr], [Store Nbr], columns, value
                    FROM POSSalesMicro
                    UNPIVOT
                    (
                       columns
                       FOR value IN('+ @cols + ')
                    ) AS u
                ) 
                insert into pivot_columns (' + @cols + ') 
                SELECT 
                  [Prime Item Nbr], 
                  [Store Nbr],
                  columns,
                  CAST(CASE WHEN value LIKE ''% POS Sales'' THEN REPLACE(value,''POS Sales'', '''')
                       WHEN value LIKE ''LR%'' THEN REPLACE(value,''LR '', '''')
                  END AS INT) AS WMWeek
                FROM Unpivoted';

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: First time i've seen dynamic with pivot. Starts to get hard to debug at that point haha. +1